# proof by contradiction that if a and b are positive integars and $ab >100$ then at least one of the integars a and b is greater than 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

does anyone know how to proof by contradiction 
that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integars and $ab >100$ then at least one of the integars $a$ and $b$ is greater than $10$

Comment: yes but you have to prove it for a and b

Comment: Sorry, I misread the last line.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: no, you read correctly; it was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, toward a contradiction, that $0<a\leq 10$ and $0<b\leq 10$. Then 
$$
  100
< ab
\leq 10\cdot 10
= 100,
$$
contradiction.

Comment: The question appears to have been changed ... I will edit my answer

Comment: I don't think a downvote is necessary. What is written is correct and would be helpful as a hint to the answer.

Comment: Indeed, two downvotes in fact. Could the downvoters comment?

Comment: There is only one downvoter. Perhaps you were noting that I had removed my upvote temporarily.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't aware. But thanks for helping me to improve the post!

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use contradiction? If not, the contrapositive is straightforward:
$$
a\le 10, \ b\le 10 \implies ab\le 100
$$

Comment: (+1) There is often little difference between proofs using the contrapositive and proofs using contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume the opposite. What is the negation of the statement "At least one of $a$ and $b$ are greater than 10"? After you form the negation, you need to simply use elementary algebra to get a contradiction.